# Laravel 5 Form Model Binding Checkbox Values

Tags: php, forms, laravel, checkbox

I am using a checkbox in a form, for some reasons I can't store the value of the checkbox status (checked or unchecked).

I am using form model binding.

My form is:

```
{!! Form::model($profile, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'action' => ['ProfilesController@update', $profile->id]]) !!}

<div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::label('wifi', 'Wifi') !!}
  {!! Form::checkbox('wifi','yes', $profile->wifi) !!}Wifi
</div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

My Schema:

```
$table->boolean('wifi')->nullable();
```

But I also tried it with an integer

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your this piece of code

```
{!! Form::checkbox('wifi','yes', $profile->wifi) !!}Wifi
```

is generating this

```
<input checked="checked" name="wifi" type="checkbox" value="yes">
```

Which means that you are sending the value `yes` to the server but your column data type is not varchar/text. You set it to boolean.

update your code to this because you are using `form model binding` so no need to popluate it, laravel will do this for you.

```
{!! Form::checkbox('wifi') !!} Wifi
```

***Also***, include your `wifi` key in `fillable` and `casts` array. like so

```
protected $fillable = [ ..., 'wifi' ];

protected $casts = [ 'wifi' => 'boolean' ];
```

**Note:** your schema code

```
$table->boolean('wifi')->nullable;
```

`nullable` is not a property, it is a function. so update it as well

```
$table->boolean('wifi')->nullable();
```

After that refersh your database migration

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

Comment: Hi Zayn, thank's. I used your example, and updated to nullable(). Still the same, the state is not saved to the DB

Comment: Yes I have refreshed my migration

Comment: Okay and in your model, have you put `wifi` in your fillable and also in the casts array? like this `protected $casts = [ 'wifi' => 'boolean' ];`

Comment: Zayn, great!!!! Thank you so much. I never heard about the Attribute Casting. That did the trick

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad it helped :)

Comment: Zayn, sorry I made a mistake. It seems like your solution doesn't work. I have used a temporary solution which I didn't commented out ({{ Form::hidden('wifi', false) }}
  {{ Form::checkbox('wifi', true) }} ). So i thought that your code works properly, but unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: By viewing the source code with your suggestion the input field has no value <input name="wifi" type="checkbox" value="" id="wifi">

Comment: Yes because false evaluates to empty not 0

Comment: but I am using the code you suggested {!! Form::checkbox('wifi', $profile->wifi, $profile->wifi) !!} Wifi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120367/discussion-between-zayn-ali-and-mamulasa).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how are you trying to persist this data.

If you're using `save()` method, do something like this:

```
$model->wifi = isset($request->wifi);
```

PS: I guess it should be `->nullable()`

Comment: Hi Alexey, I am using: public function update(ProfileRequest $request, $id)
    {
      $profile = Profile::findOrFail($id);
      $profile->update($request->all());
      return redirect('backend/profile');
    }

Comment: Then try to do this `$request->wifi = isset($request->wifi);` right before `$profile->update($request->all());`. And also, in your case, you should have `wifi` in a `$fillable` array of `Profile` model.

Comment: ok, wifi is in a fillable array and I updated my Controller to: public function update(ProfileRequest $request, $id)
    {
      $profile = Profile::findOrFail($id);
      $request->wifi = isset($request->wifi);
      $profile->update($request->all());
      return redirect('backend/profile');
    } But still the same :(

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Do you have any error? If not, what does 'dd(iseet($request->wifi))` says when checkbox is checked and when it's not?